# Deploy JNLP applet *without* Next Gen Java Plugin

Tags: java, html, applet, jnlp, java-web-start

I need to deploy an applet on a .jsp page and want to take advantage of lazy loading and pack200 that you get when using JNLP. However my client does not have the Next Gen Java Plugin enabled on their machines and they do not want to enable it. This means I can not take advantage of the `jnlp_href` attribute introduced in java 1.6.10.

After some research I discovered you can specify an `applet-desc` in my jnlp but I am new to JNLP and do not know how to fully take advantage of this tag.

I have not seen any solid examples of how to use a JNLP file on a webpage without using the applet or object tags which require the `jnlp_href` param attribute.

Is it possible using this `applet-desc` tag to inject a reference to my JNLP in my .jsp page?

Currently I specify my applet using the object HTML element like this:

```
<object code="<myappletClass>" name="pdfapplet" codebase="<myCodeBase>" mayscript>
        <param name="jnlp_href" value="my-applet.jnlp"/>
</object>
```

However this does not grab the `jnlp_href` with Java plugin turned off in the Java console.

Comment: `applet-desc` still runs the applet in its own window. It's just a (pretty pointless) compatibility feature to get applets running as WebStart applications.

Comment: Read the 5th paragraph shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  In fact, read all of it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ok so it seems you can point a link to a jnlp file for that file to load the application/applet in a new window, but you cannot embed a jnlp file to load in a webpage with other html content. Is that correct?

Comment: Pre the Next Gen. Plug-In, yes.  To flesh out Tom's point, if you are going to launch it free-floating, you might as well make it frame based to begin with.  Then you can easily customize the frame (which for an applet, shown using the applet viewer, is quite ugly).

Answer (score 1):

If the applet does not need to be embedded in the web page, it can be launched free-floating from the first versions of [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) (available as a separate download around Java 1.2).  It is only in the [Next Generation JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/next-generation-plugin/info) that a JWS deployed applet can remain **embedded** in a web page.